# In angular when i login how to set timeout and navigate away form that route?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angular-router, auth-guard

Here is the function:

```
onSubmit(value){
this.authService.login(value.email, value.password)
.then(
  res=> {})
.catch(error=>
          {console.log(error);}
 )
}
```

I think in the res I have to set timeout. I have the authGuard that's why I need the timeout.

Comment: are you using Promise with Observable? if yes, can you show how you have implemented it?

Comment: There is no need of using a timeout with auth-guard. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

change it to this;

```
onSubmit(value){
   this.authService.login(value.email, value.password)
   .then(
      res=> {
        setTimeout(()=>{this.navigateByUrl('/home');}, 1000);
      })
   .catch(error=>
      {console.log(error);}
    )
}
```

hope it helps;